# how to adjust the cell aligment in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have used the WordWrap function of fpdf but because of that the cell alignment is getting distorted. 
Extra blank columns are getting added and the other cells are getting affected.
Here is the code. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php 
require('fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
function WordWrap(&$text, $maxwidth)
{
    $text = trim($text);
    if ($text==='')
        return 0;
    $space = $this->GetStringWidth(' ');
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    $text = '';
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        $words = preg_split('/ +/', $line);
        $width = 0;

        foreach ($words as $word)
        {
            $wordwidth = $this->GetStringWidth($word);
            if ($wordwidth > $maxwidth)
            {
                // Word is too long, we cut it
                for($i=0; $i<strlen($word); $i++)
                {
                    $wordwidth = $this->GetStringWidth(substr($word, $i, 1));
                    if($width + $wordwidth <= $maxwidth)
                    {
                        $width += $wordwidth;
                        $text .= substr($word, $i, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $width = $wordwidth;
                        $text = rtrim($text)."\n".substr($word, $i, 1);
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($width + $wordwidth <= $maxwidth)
            {
                $width += $wordwidth + $space;
                $text .= $word.' ';
            }
            else
            {
                $width = $wordwidth + $space;
                $text = rtrim($text)."\n".$word.' ';
                $count++;
            }
        }
        $text = rtrim($text)."\n";
        $count++;
    }
    $text = rtrim($text);
    return $text;
}
}

$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
define("DBHOST","localhost");
define("DBNAME","users");
define("DBUSER","root");
define("PASS","");
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,DBUSER,PASS);
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT name,email,mobile,address,language FROM users ");
$query->execute();
$datas = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(20,7,'Name',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,7,'Email',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,7,'Mobile',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,7,'Address',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,7,'Language',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
foreach ($datas as $row)
{
    $pdf->Cell(20,7,$row['name'],1);
    $pdf->Cell(50,7,$row['email'],1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,$row['mobile'],1);

    $text = "An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic";
    $pdf->WordWrap($text,30);
    $pdf->Cell(50,7,$pdf->Write(4,$text),1);
    //$pdf->write("<br>");
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,$row['language'],1);
    $pdf->Ln();
}
//$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
// $text='An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic';
// $pdf->WordWrap($text,15);
// $pdf->Cell(10,0,$pdf->Write(4,$text));
// $pdf->Write(5,"This paragraph has $nb lines:\n\n");
//  $pdf->Write(4,$text);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic"
$wrapped = wordwrap($str,15)
$pdf->Cell(50,7,$wrapped,1);
$pdf->Write("<br>");
```

---

Read

1. [Word wrap](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script49.php)
2. [Write HTML](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/write.htm)

Comment: I am getting the error Fatal error: Call to undefined method FPDF::WriteHTML()

Comment: Sorry. Try `write`

Comment: it is still not working giving me an 'error issing argument 2 for FPDF::Write()'

Comment: remove that and run.

Comment: still not working the text is not wrapping it is still going in another cell.